# aggregate the data to one column using unique value

Tags: r, aggregate

I have a data frame  yy.  I want to do a aggregation of the data. There is a time stamp variable and there is repetition in the time variable.
I want to find the unique values of time stamp  and aggregate all the other variables in this data frame  with respect to this unique time stamp value. Finally I need to get the mean of the other variables.
Here is the data sample

```
 temp yield density          time
1   54    NA   30.23 2009-12-31 18
2   54    NA   30.22 2009-12-31 19
3   53    NA   30.20 2009-12-31 20
4   53    NA   30.19 2009-12-31 21
5   50    NA   30.18 2009-12-31 22
6   51     3   30.16 2009-12-31 23
.......
```

I  run the following code:

```
aggdata=aggregate(yy~time, by= list(unique(time)), data =yy, FUN = mean,na.rm=TRUE)
```

I got this warning

> argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

If I run the aggregation one  variable at a time,  it works

```
aggdata=aggregate(temp~time, by= list(unique(time)),data=yy,FUN=mean)
```

But if use the whole data list yy, there are errors.
Could someone please explain this?

Comment: Looking at the help page `?aggregate`, I see no syntax like `aggregate(formula, by, data, FUN)`. Maybe you need to pick among the supported syntaxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `data.table`, convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(yy)`), grouped by 'time', specify the columns to summarise in `.SDcols`, loop through them and get the `mean`.

```
 library(data.table)
 setDT(yy)[, lapply(.SD, mean, na.rm=TRUE), by = time, .SDcols = c("temp", "yield")]
```

Comment: here by = time so it will return and aggregate with unique value of time?

Comment: @newleaf Yes it will aggregate by unique value of time

Comment: This is fast and neat. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like something that could easily be done using the package `dplyr`

You could do something as follows:

```
yy <- yy %>% group_by(time) %>% summarize(meantemp = mean(temp), meanyield = mean(yield))
```